# Split string into multiple maps/lists in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a list with maps like this:

> List = { [name:'A:B:C'],[name:'A:B:D'],[name:'A:B:E'],[name:'A:F'] }

and I want to convert this list into map like that:

```
Map = [{
   'name': 'A',
   'child': [ {
      'name': 'B',
      'child' : [
         {'name':'C', 'child':[]}, {'name': 'D', 'child':[]}, {'name': 'E', 'child':[]}
       ]
    },
    {
      'name':'F',
      'child': []
    }]
}]
```

in groovy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one method...  I have a feeling there may be much easier routes to the same answer ;-)

```
def list = [ [ name:'A:B:C' ], [ name:'A:B:D' ], [ name:'A:B:E' ], [ name:'A:F' ] ]

Map convertToMap( List list ) {
    def map = [child:[]]
    list.name*.tokenize( ':' ).each { names ->
        def current = map
        names.each { name ->
            def next = current.child.find { it.name == name }
            if( !next ) {
                next = [ name: name, child:[] ]
                current.child << next
            }
            current = next
        }
    }
    map.child[ 0 ]
}

convertToMap( list )
```

I'll have a think...

#### Edit:

You can do this, but we might be getting a bit esoteric ;-)

```
def list = [ [ name:'A:B:C' ], [ name:'A:B:D' ], [ name:'A:B:E' ], [ name:'A:F' ] ]

def tree = { [:].withDefault{ owner.call() } }
def map = list.name*.tokenize( ':' ).inject( tree() ) { t, names ->
    names.inject( t ) { tr, name -> tr."$name" }
    t
}.collectEntries { k, v ->
    [ name:k, child:v.collect( { owner }() ) ]
}
```